# Is this linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, signal-processing

> For noiseless data, we can define two $(N-L)\times L$ matrices, $Y_1$ and $Y_2$, defined by
>   \begin{align}
> [Y_2] &= \begin{bmatrix}
> x(1) & x(2) &\cdots& x(L)\\
> x(2) & x(3) &\cdots& x(L+1)\\
> \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
> x(N-L-1)& x(N-L)&\cdots&x(N-1)
> \end{bmatrix}_{(N-L)\times L}\\
> [Y_1] &=\begin{bmatrix}
> x(0) & x(1) &\cdots& x(L-1)\\
> x(1) & x(2) &\cdots& x(L)\\
> \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
> x(N-L-1)& x(N-L)&\cdots&x(N-2)
> \end{bmatrix}_{(N-L)XL.}
> \end{align}

I look at this and read it as "two N minus L times L matrices".

I don't have a mathematics background but I need to interpret this paper for an ongoing research project.

**Where do you recommend I begin my search (any books, related terms or mathematical concepts I should learn about would be very appreciated)!**

My hope is to implement the formulations on page 3 in Matlab.

This is the math-filled, Signal Processing paper by the way: https://sci-hub.tw/10.1109/74.370583 (trying to extract frequencies and amplitudes of a signal after removing noise that came from the instrument/receiver).

Comment: You probably could do with a more numerical linear algebra understanding, which can be done via a plentitude of sources (Coursera, mit.ocw, plenty of textbooks)

Comment: I recommend looking at Introduction to Linear Algebra by Strang.

Comment: If your goal is to be able to understand this paper I don't think it is realistic that you would be able to do so in a semester. That's not a slight at your intellect. Just reading it briefly though you would need curriculum from both a first and second course in linear algebra, complex variables, and statistics/probability. Here are some search terms you might choose though: variance (statistics), moore-penrose pseudoinverse, complex exponential, singular value decomposition, eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Comment: This 'Matrix Pencil Method' seems to be a technique in linear algebra as states its wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_pencil . I've never heard about it though. It is certainly not standard material on a regular course on linear algebra. There is a couple references in the wikipedia page which may be useful to you.